# `Apply` function doesn't work as expected

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm using Mathematica 12.2. I've just got surprised when the following simple line of code does not work properly.

This is my input (as simple as it could):

```
Apply[D[#, y] &, f[y] + g[y]]
```

In which I want to differentiate sum of two functions (`f` and `g`) with respect to `y`. This is my output :

```
f'[y]
```

which is different from the expected result (`f'[y]+g'[y]`)!

as could be seen in the following picture :

[image]

could any one explain why should I get such result ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Trace`

```
Apply[D[#, y] &, f[y] + g[y]] // Trace // Column
```

[image: 1]

What you want is `Map`

```
Map[D[#, y] &, f[y] + g[y]]
```

```
Derivative[1][f][y] + Derivative[1][g][y]
```

Comment: Also `D[#, y] &[f[y] + g[y]]`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer shows you what is happening, but it doesn't really illustrate *why* it is happening.  If you look at the documentation for `Apply[f,expr]`, you will note that what it does is it replaces the head of `expr` with `f`.  But for the given expression, the head of `expr` is not the full expression itself, but `Plus`.  You can see this by typing `Head[f[y] + g[y]` or `FullForm[f[y] + g[y]]`.  So when you replace `Plus` that has two arguments with the function `D[#, y] &` that has one argument, only the first argument in the sequence is differentiated, and the second is lost.